# User does not exist when resetting WSL password

Tags: sudo, password, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I haven't used sudo on a command in a while, and recently when I tried to do this the password was wrong. This is read off of a post it note on my desk and has always worked for me before. I followed instructions online to reset the password. From the command prompt:

```
>wsl -u root
>passwd <username>
passwd: user 'username' does not exist
```

If I try getent passwd in the command prompt I don't see the username listed. However if I try getent passwd in the WSL ubuntu window the user is the last one listed. Obviously I can't use passwd in the WSL window because then it asks for the previous password. I have seen people need to reset their password OR not have a user exist, but I haven't seen someone deal with both yet. Any suggestions? Any reason why a password would stop working?

Comment: In WSL, did you ever create a password for the user using `passwd`?

Comment: Is it possible that you have multiple distros installed under WSL, and that the default one that you enter with `wsl -u root` is different from the one where you are seeing your username via `getent passwd`? What is the output of `wsl --list`?

Comment: Thank you sir @steeldriver this was worthy as an actual answer. Fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following @steeldriver's suggestion in the comments, I switched the default distro for WSL via the command line in windows. This allowed me to use `passwd <username>` and reset my password.

Comment: Can you edit your answer to explain the steps. in my case i was defaulted to docker causing the issue and this would be an acceptable answer.